# Where am I supposed to be pulling these basic Java classes from?

Tags: java, react-native

Maybe the question is too basic and that's why I can't find any information on it - but I am fairly new to Java and I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve this error.

I am writing a Native Bridge module in React Native, and I found a function online to convert between Javascript data structures and Java data structures. So far so good.

```
    private static JSONArray convertArrayToJson(ReadableArray readableArray) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < readableArray.size(); i++) {
        switch (readableArray.getType(i)) {
        case Null:
            break;
        case Boolean:
            array.put(readableArray.getBoolean(i));
            break;
        case Number:
            array.put(readableArray.getDouble(i));
            break;
        case String:
            array.put(readableArray.getString(i));
            break;
        case Map:
            array.put(convertMapToJson(readableArray.getMap(i)));
            break;
        case Array:
            array.put(convertArrayToJson(readableArray.getArray(i)));
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

However when trying to compile, I am getting a bunch of build errors from these basic data structures being missing. Do I need to import them from somewhere?

```
  symbol:   variable Null
  location: class PayPalMobileRN
/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada_androidrn/android/app/src/main/java/com/paypal-rn-sdk/PayPalMobileRN.java:346: error: cannot find symbol
            case Boolean:
                 ^
  symbol:   variable Boolean
  location: class PayPalMobileRN
/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada_androidrn/android/app/src/main/java/com/paypal-rn-sdk/PayPalMobileRN.java:349: error: cannot find symbol
            case Number:
                 ^
  symbol:   variable Number
  location: class PayPalMobileRN
/Users/andy/Desktop/Projects/pinyada_androidrn/android/app/src/main/java/com/paypal-rn-sdk/PayPalMobileRN.java:352: error: cannot find symbol
            case String:
```

As far as I can tell, these should be in java.lang:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.lang.Boolean;
import java.lang.Null;
import java.lang.Number;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Map;
import java.lang.Array;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeArray;
```

But despite importing all of these, I am still getting this build error.

Am I pulling from the wrong place?

Comment: what type of object does `readableMap.getType(key)` return?

Comment: Oops copied the wrong function. I actually want readableArray. Corrected. All of the ReadableArray methods are available here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableArray.java

Comment: You need to either statically import them from `ReadableType`, or use `ReadableType.Null` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't switch on classes. Those are actually enum constants with unconventional casing. Just import [`ReadableType`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableType.java) and you should be good to go.